# How to connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 from PHP with dblib

Tags: php, database

I am using the following line of code to connect to a SQL Server 2008 version from PHP:

```
$dbh = new PDO('dblib:host=xx.xx.xx.xx;port=xxxx;dbname=xxxxxx', 'username', 'password');
```

From this I get:

```
Error!: SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: 
Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)
```

The above database settings work fine with `pdo_mssql` on by dev machine, but Bluehost does not support `pdo_mssql`.

I am on a shared hosting (Bluehost) so cannot administer the server/host.

If this is not possible then can anyone please suggest an alternative hosting provider that supports `pdo_mssql`?

Comment: Are there any error logs you can enable like suggested in this answer?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101719/php-error-connecting-to-ms-sql-database-using-pdo-dblib

Comment: I read that befre,, but No i cannot enable the logs.