# Trouble With Connecting to MSSQL DB

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, odbc, freetds

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 server and I'm trying to establish a connection to a MSSQL database.

I've managed to connect using `tsql` and `isql`, but `osql` doesn't work and connecting with PHP using PDO also isn't working.. I will try to provide as much information as I can and if you need more just let me know and I will edit.

**freetds.conf**:

```
[MSSQL]
  host = TPSACC
  port = 54488
  tds version = 8.0
```

**odbc.ini**:

```
[MSSQL]
Description     = MS SQL connection to PRODUCTION database
Driver          = FreeTDS
Database        = PRODUCTION
Server          = TPSACC
UserName        = sa
Password        = pass
Trace           = No
TDS_Version     = 8.0
Port            = 54488
```

**odbcinst.ini**:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = ODBC for Microsoft SQL
Driver      = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
UsageCount  = 1
Threading   = 2
```

**~> isql MSSQL sa pass**

```
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
```

**~> tsql -S MSSQL -U 'sa' -P 'pass'**

```
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
1>
```

**~> osql -S MSSQL -U sa -P pass**

```
checking shared odbc libraries linked to isql for default directories...
strings: '': No such file
    trying /tmp/sql ... no
    trying /tmp/sql ... no
    trying /etc ... OK
checking odbc.ini files
    reading /home/toolplas/.odbc.ini
[MSSQL] not found in /home/toolplas/.odbc.ini
    reading /etc/odbc.ini
[MSSQL] found in /etc/odbc.ini
found this section:
    [MSSQL]
    Description     = MS SQL connection to PRODUCTION database
    Driver          = FreeTDS
    Database        = PRODUCTION
    Server          = TPSACC
    UserName        = sa
    Password        = pass
    Trace           = No
    TDS_Version     = 8.0
    Port            = 54488
looking for driver for DSN [MSSQL] in /etc/odbc.ini
  found driver line: "  Driver          = FreeTDS"
  driver "FreeTDS" found for [MSSQL] in odbc.ini
found driver named "FreeTDS"
"FreeTDS" is not an executable file
looking for entry named [FreeTDS] in /etc/odbcinst.ini
  found driver line: "  Driver      = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so"
  found driver /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so for [FreeTDS] in odbcinst.ini
/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so is an executable file
"Server" found, not using freetds.conf
Server is "TPSACC"
osql: no IP address found for "TPSACC"
```

In PHP I have:

```
$conn = new PDO ("dblib:host=TPSACC;dbname=PRODUCTION","$username","$pw");
```

..or..

```
$conn = new PDO ("dblib:host=TPSACC;port=54488;dbname=PRODUCTION","$username","$pw");
```

And they both return this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)
```

I have been stuck here for a couple days and can't quite figure out why only half of the connections actually work..

Any and all help is really appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: It is different than that question, I explained in a comment but will repost here:

For that one the problem was that the port was changed from 1433. Mine was also changed and I fixed that, the port is now 54488 and since that change tsql and isql have been working. However, it still doesn't solve the osql and PHP issues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP error connecting to MS SQL database using PDO\_DBLIB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101719/php-error-connecting-to-ms-sql-database-using-pdo-dblib)

Comment: For that one the problem was that the port was changed from 1433. Mine was also changed and I fixed that, the port is now 54488 and since that change tsql and isql have been working. However, it still doesn't solve the osql and PHP issues.

Answer (score 1):

`osql` is choking on something in your configuration. `osql` is a debugging utility which simply checks out your configuration, then passes along to unixODBC's `isql` to connect (http://linux.die.net/man/1/osql). Try this for your odbc.ini:

```
[MSSQL]
Driver = FreeTDS
Description = MS SQL connection to PRODUCTION database
Server = tpsacc.yourfulldomain.com
Port = 54488
TDS_Version = 7.2
Database = PRODUCTION
UserName = sa
Password = pass
Trace = No
```

Also, are you sure that's the correct location for libtdsodbc.so? When I install freetds-dev with Ubuntu 14 x64 (utopic), it installs to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so; example odbcinst.ini:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = v0.91 with protocol v7.2
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
```

And for good measure, the typical freetds.conf I use:

```
# A typical Microsoft server
[MSSQL]
host = tpsacc.yourfulldomain.com
port = 54488
tds version = 7.2
```

FreeTDS only supports up to TDS version 7.2 with most languages. While using "8.0" shouldn't break anything, using 7.2 is better for consistency. If you need to check for reference, I have a Vagrant box with a full configuration available here, with examples: https://github.com/FlipperPA/django-python3-vagrant/ Good luck!

Comment: Hello and thank you for the reply! I'm sorry but I'm a little confused.. "tpsacc.domain.com".. I don't have a domain attached to this, I can only use either TPSACC *or* the IP address (10.0.1.2). Also I checked the directory for the driver that you say and the drivers are there as well.. So I should be using that one instead ?? Even though it is also in the directory that I had before?

Comment: when I changed the Driver to the one you tell me I get this error `/usr/lib/x86_64-lunix-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so is not an executable file` ..

Comment: Wups, sorry, I didn't mean you should definitely change the path - just that it was worth looking into. How did you install FreeTDS?

Comment: Rather than actually using tpsacc.domain.com, I was using an example with a FQDN (fully qualified domain name). You could also try the IP address in its place.

Comment: I've tried the IP address and still no luck. I'm just curious if the freetds.conf / odbc.ini / odbcinst.ini have an affect on PDO? If so then why does everything need to be declared again in PHP (host, db, port, etc..) ? Honestly I installed FreeTDS a very long time ago (few months) and I don't remember exactly how, I just know that I wasn't able to get ./configure && make to work... Do you think I'm better off purging freetds and starting from scratch?

Comment: If you're on Ubuntu, take a look here: https://github.com/FlipperPA/django-python3-vagrant/tree/master/examples  Specifically, `install-mssql.sh` is literally all the commands I use to install what's needed to connect to SQL Server, and the freetds / odbc config files are included with examples as well. A clean, fresh start might be best.