# mssql connection in linux

Tags: php, pdo

I try to connect sqlserver with pdo dblib in VM centos6 x64. runing the php page below:

```
try{
$dsn = "dblib:host=192.168.5.101;dbname=webfilter";
$user = "myuser";
$password = "mypass";
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
echo "connection successfull";
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
echo "error message:".$e->getMessage();
}
```

and this page prints: "error message:SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)" 
What does it mean ? I make simple search in net but not clear solution and none of them helped my my problem is not about connection string.

and here some of phpinfo contents:
PDO drivers:    dblib, mysql, sqlite

Flavour:    freetds

(I can ping and log in to sql server in windows host)

**EDITED**
tried connect with tsql command:

```
root@company-gwfilter:~ # tsql -S 192.168.5.101 -U myuser -P 'mypass' -L webfilter
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Error 20009 (severity 9):
    Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
    OS error 111, "Connection refused"
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

At least I can see there is a problem now.. but cant find what it is.. I checked port sqlserver 1433, and I edit freetds.conf with this host settings but still same error

Comment: Are you able to ping this ip `192.168.5.101` from your server???

Comment: Yes, I can ping and connect the mssql

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101719/php-error-connecting-to-ms-sql-database-using-pdo-dblib)

Comment: I checked and edit the freetds.conf and restarted apache but still same

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue, change sql server instance port:
SQL Server Network Configuration -> TCP/IP (enable it) -> IP Addresses -> IPAll -> TCP Dynamic Ports.
And edit freetds.conf in Linux with same port then connection is successfull.

I hope this helps who suffer same problem.